# load csv file into R: "\" change to "\\"

Tags: r, csv

I try to read one csv file into R, but the values with "\" change to ones with "\ \" automaticlly. For example, "A \B" changes to "A \ \B". How could I keep them no change?
Thanks.

Comment: The value isn't changing, that's just how R draws it in the console. If you `cat()` that value, you should see only one slash. In R, you  need to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Does `cat(some-column-with-single-backslash)` show as one or two backslashes?

Comment: The function "cat" can show it correctly, but cannot use for other purposes. Right? For example, I want to use "\n" to plot a dozen of figures with two-line titles. > plot(1:5,main="A \nB")
> plot(1:5,main="A \\nB")
> plot(1:5,main=cat("A \\nB"))

Comment: Well, a `\ ` is different than a `\n`. Normally a slash makes the next character special. So `\t` is a <tab> and `\n` is a <new line>. But `\\ ` is just a slash. Those are all technically one character wide. If you want to replace the `\ ` with `\n` to print on multiple lines, you can do that, but that seems unrelated to your original question.